# I am trying to make onclick function work in a tr element

Tags: javascript

I have a page that worked well enough without a table but the page size just got too big.  I decided to break it up into tables to clean it up.  once i did the hyperlinks quit working.  I don't mean the broke but when I click on them nothing happens.  here is the code i am using. when I run this page all of the cell contents show up blue and the pointer changes like a hyperlink but when I click literally nothing happens. no event no errors in the console no nothing.  any thoughts??

```js
function editScreenAvian() {
  $source = "../DMKgenavianv1.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenBovine() {
  $source = "./DMKgenbovinev3.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenPorcine() {
  $source = "../DMKGenPorcinev1.phpcaseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenIAVA() {
  $source = "./DMKIAVAv1.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenIAVS() {
  $source = "./DMKIAVsv1.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenQuickBovine() {
  $source = "./DMKQuickbovinev3.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenQuickPorcine() {
  $source = "./DMKQuickPorcinev3.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenRabies() {
  $source = "./DMKGenRabiesNoHistov3.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenRabiesNo() {
  $source = "./DMKGenRabiesHistov3.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenSDAIBS() {
  $source = "./DMKSDMIvi.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenNDMI() {
  $source = "./DMKNDMIvi.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenVTMI() {
  $source = "./DMKVTMIvi.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

function editScreenGENMI() {
  $source = "./DMKFoodSafetyv2.php?caseNumber=<?=$caseNumber;?>";
  loadIFrame();
  return;
}

let $caseDefaultKey = "<?=$caseDefault?>";
if ($caseDefaultKey === "11") {
  editScreenSDAIBS();
}
if ($caseDefaultKey === "50") {
  editScreenIAVA()();
}
if ($caseDefaultKey === "53") {
  editScreenBovine();
}
if ($caseDefaultKey === "") {
  editScreenPorcine()
}






function loadIFrame() {
  $("#divEntryArea").html('<iframe style="margin-left: 0vw; width: 64vw; height: 100vh; border: none; margin-right: 0;" src=\'' + $source + '&noHeading=Y\'></iframe>');
}
```

```html
<center>
  <b><font size="+1">title 1 </b></font><br>
</center>
<table width=65% border=1 align="right">

  <td width=5%> <a onclick="editScreenAvian()">cell 1<br></td>
        <td width=5%>  <a onclick='editScreenBovine()'>cell 2</a><br></td>
  <td width=5%> <a onclick='editScreenPorcine()'>cell 3</a><br></td>

  </tr>
</table><br>

<iframe style="margin-left: 36vw; width: 64vw; height: 100vh; border: none; margin-right: 0;" '>    </iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="caseSpecimens" class="handsontable"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are using deprecated html tags

Comment: You are missing a closing anchor tag. I do not see an opening tr tag on the row with the links. My guess is these little things are the cause of your issues.

Comment: And you are using the deprecated tags incorrectly as well (nesting overlapping).

Comment: Where is divEntryArea? Your HTML is really in need of a facelift and you need to make your functions DRY

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're not opening the 'tr' tag and not closing the first 'a' tag. You should also fix the code identation. I think that's it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Since you took the time to figure out what was wrong here, it could be really helpful to include a code snippet showing the author. Especially when there's a lot of code, it's hard to understand exactly what to change. Otherwise, thanks for taking the time to answer :)